# PDO SQL injection (fetching variable from url)

Tags: mysql, pdo, bind

I have an id that is passed in the URL (e.g. id=33). It is always a number.

I used to use the standard mysql to connect and use escape string and int to make secure etc.

I'm trying to move onto PDO and I think the code below is secure (is working fine) but would really appreciate it is anyone on here could take a look and let me know if I've missed anything/any suggestions on improving the security.

```
$pdo    = new PDO($dsn, '*****','*****');

$id = $_GET["id"];
$id = filter_var($id, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);  
if (filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {  
$sql    = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
$sql->bindParam(":id",$id);
$row    = $sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Am I correct in thinking the above is secure (using the below to echo the data):

```
<?php echo ($result['colour']);?>
```

Again, thanks in advance for any help :)

p.s. on a side note, I'm assuming if I used:

```
<?php echo ($result['id']);?>
```

this would pull the sanitized ID not the one from the get statement?

EDIT
just to clarify, no users will have access to submit data (this will all be done by myself via phpmyadmin. The only thing they will see is a list of names and when clicked it takes them to a page (with the ID in the URL) showing the colours associated to there name.

Comment: Yes. Combining `filter_var()` with `bindParam` is. You're validating it as an integer (holding only [0-9]+). Would validate the value of `colour` before output, as this is user input?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your feedback, much appreciated. 
Only the ID is user input, everything else is manually entered into the database

Comment: Depending on your error handling, I would check `id` exists in the query string - but that's more of a UX POV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're disciplined about using placeholders you shouldn't have any problems with your database security. PDO will take care of properly escaping things. Note this doesn't mean your query will be valid or that the data will be saved as you expect, you may have problems with truncation or conversion.

Keep in mind you'll need to be just as vigilant about presenting data stored in your database to avoid HTML issues and [XSS problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). This requires escaping data for presentation, for example the [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) method.

Comment: Hi, all data inputted into the database will be done by myself via phpmyadmin. No users will have access to this / be able to submit data (no forms for them). The only side the users will see is the front end with a list of names etc, once clicked the ID is passed into the URL so the persons details can be loaded (colour).

Do you think I need to make any changes to the output to avoid any XSS since no user input is made (other than the URL ID)?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No, you're only doing a lookup with an integer - which you've ensured is an integer. The rest of your application would need to be looked at though.

Comment: Just be careful with any assumptions you make. *Today* you're in control of the data, but does that hold true in the future? People make mistakes, scope changes. Try not to leave traps for yourself in the future where you've forgotten to escape something. I usually test with data like `'<strong>"test☃"</strong>'` to see if quoting, HTML escaping, and UTF-8 is handled correctly.

Comment: Hi, the data in the database also contains HTML so I'm not sure if I can do much to limit this. However, the database user is a stand alone user with only read privileges so this should (I believe) stop any edits should a weakness be found (correct me if I'm wrong).